# List users who have the maximum number of processes running with maximum cpu usage

Tags: users, csv

starting off with the command

```
ps -eo user,pcpu,pid,args | sort -rnk 3 | head -30
```

How do i parse the output of this command into a csv file with users having most processess and consuming cpu usage? any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/), and run

```
ps -eo user,pcpu | mlr  --n2c  --repifs -N cat | mlr --csv stats1 -f "%CPU" -a count,sum -g USER
```

to get something like this

| USER | %CPU_count | %CPU_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| root | 8 | 0.000000 |
| username | 8 | 0.200000 |
| mysql | 1 | 0.000000 |
| www-data | 5 | 0.000000 |

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -eo user,pmem,pcpu,pid,args --no-headers | sort -rnk 3,3 | head -n30 | awk '{ print $1 "," $3 "," $5 }'
```

Added the `--no-headers` option to `ps`, since otherwise the header line is sometimes in the output. This assumes there will never be a comma in any of the output fields, and so CSV escaping logic is unnecessary. If you do need CSV escaping logic, you should probably write in Python or something and use the module; CSV escaping logic is painful.

Comment: the last columns has spaces in it , so it is only getting the first word and leaving the rest of the command in the last column, how do i stop that.

Comment: for ex: DSD.RUN BGHRPSHDWJ4 , i get only DSR.RUN and the rest of the command is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work for you:

```
ps -eo user,pmem,pcpu,pid,args | sort -rnk 3 | head -30 | awk '{OFS=","; print $1,$3,$5}'
```

---

<sub>This answers your first question, before you edited it</sub>

Answer (score 0):

perhaps a little dirty but works:

```
ps -eo user,pmem,pcpu,pid,args --no-headers | sort -rnk 3,3 | head -n 30 | awk '{ print $1 "," $3 "," $5 " " $6 " " $7 " " $8 " " $9 " " $10 " " $11 " " $12 " " $13}'
```

Comment: yes, i found the answer and then looked at ur comment , a little "as long as it works kinda thing" but works ok.so, can i sort the output with username , so repeatin users list together?

Comment: how do i add another column that shows the current time??